# 8-bit fletcher checksum of 16 byte data

Tags: c, microcontroller, crc

I'm trying to implement a 8-bit fletcher checksum function.

My data will always be 17 byte long.

I started with code from [Remake of Fletcher checksum from 32bit to 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925018/remake-of-fletcher-checksum-from-32bit-to-8)

Here is what I ended up having :

```c
// 8-bit Fletcher checksum
//   data is always 17 byte long
uint8_t fletcher(uint8_t *data) {
    uint8_t sum1 = 0x0f, sum2 = 0x0f, len = 17;

    while(len) {
        sum1 += *data++;
        sum2 += sum1;
        sum1 = (sum1 & 0x0f) + (sum1 >> 4);
        sum2 = (sum2 & 0x0f) + (sum2 >> 4);
        len--;
    }
    sum1 = (sum1 & 0x0f) + (sum1 >> 4);
    sum2 = (sum2 & 0x0f) + (sum2 >> 4);
    return sum2<<4 | sum1;
}
```

I'm wondering if it is good and I have the impression that I could simplify further but I can't find where (maybe it just can't be simplified further after all ...).

My main question is whether this code looks it will work okay. I am using it at both sides of a wireless based data link it will "work" (return the same checksum from the same data) but may be wrong in the fletcher way and not provide the expected error detection ...

Hope I'm clear enough ...

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 6):

First off, any variant of Fletcher is not a CRC.  It's a checksum.

Second, there is nothing special about the number of bytes you process as long as the algorithm is correct.

Third, you do not need to and should not be doing the modulo 15 at every step.  For speed (which is the whole point of a Fletcher sum as compared to a CRC), there should be an inner loop that only consists of `sum2 += sum1 += *data++;`.  Depending on the size of the `sum1` and `sum2` data types, you can calculate how many iterations you can do before overflowing `sum2` assuming that all input bytes are `0xff`.  Then an outer loop runs that inner loop that many times followed by the two modulo 15's.  The outer loops runs through all of the input data.

Fourth, the `(x >> 4) + (x & 0xf)` operations do not complete the intended `x % 15` when `x` ends up as 15.  There would need to be a final `if (x == 15) x = 0;`.

*Update:*

Ok, so here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXPART 5803    /* for 32-bit unsigned sum1, sum2 */
/* #define MAXPART 22   for 16-bit unsigned sum1, sum2 */

unsigned fletcher8(unsigned f8, unsigned char *data, size_t len)
{
    unsigned long sum1, sum2;
    size_t part;

    sum1 = f8 & 0xf;
    sum2 = (f8 >> 4) & 0xf;
    while (len) {
        part = len > MAXPART ? MAXPART : len;
        len -= part;
        do {
            sum2 += sum1 += *data++;
        } while (--part);
        sum1 %= 15;
        sum2 %= 15;
    }
    return (sum2 << 4) + sum1;
}

#define SIZE 131072

int main(void)
{
    unsigned f8 = 1;
    unsigned char buf[SIZE];
    size_t got;

    while ((got = fread(buf, 1, SIZE, stdin)) > 0)
        f8 = fletcher8(f8, buf, got);
    printf("0x%02x\n", f8);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that I started the Fletcher8 value at `1` instead of `0xff`.  That is sufficient to assure that a string of any length of zeros will produce the same zero result.  You can set the initial value to whatever you like, so long as it's not zero.

If the modulo (`%`) operation on the machine is very slow, then it may be faster to do the `% 15` operations with a set of shifts and adds.  Here is an example for a 32-bit type:

```
k = (k >> 16) + (k & 0xffff);
k = (k >> 8) + (k & 0xff);
k = (k >> 4) + (k & 0xf);
k = (k >> 4) + (k & 0xf);
if (k > 14)
    k -= 15;
```

For the stated case where `len == 17`, the code can be simplified to use `unsigned` instead of `unsigned long` for `sum1` and `sum2`, and to skip the outer loop since `len <= 22`.  The non-% modulo operations can be shortened as well.  Here's that, where I also eliminated an unnecessary decrement operation in the loop:

```
unsigned fletch8_17(unsigned char *data)
{
    unsigned sum1 = 1;
    unsigned sum2 = 0;
    unsigned char *end = data + 17;
    do {
        sum2 += sum1 += *data++;
    } while (data < end);
    sum1 = (sum1 >> 8) + (sum1 & 0xff);
    sum1 = (sum1 >> 4) + (sum1 & 0xf);
    if (sum1 > 14) {
        sum1 -= 15;
        if (sum1 > 14)
            sum1 -= 15;
    }
    sum2 = (sum2 >> 8) + (sum2 & 0xff);
    sum2 = (sum2 >> 4) + (sum2 & 0xf);
    if (sum2 > 14) {
        sum2 -= 15;
        if (sum2 > 14)
            sum2 -= 15;
    }
    return (sum2 << 4) + sum1;
}
```

For comparison, you can try this 8-bit CRC and see how it compares for speed (crc should be initialized to zero):

```
#include <stddef.h>

/* 8-bit CRC with polynomial x^8+x^6+x^3+x^2+1, 0x14D.
 Chosen based on Koopman, et al. (0xA6 in his notation = 0x14D >> 1):
 http://www.ece.cmu.edu/~koopman/roses/dsn04/koopman04_crc_poly_embedded.pdf
 */

static unsigned char crc8_table[] = {
    0x00, 0x3e, 0x7c, 0x42, 0xf8, 0xc6, 0x84, 0xba, 0x95, 0xab, 0xe9, 0xd7,
    0x6d, 0x53, 0x11, 0x2f, 0x4f, 0x71, 0x33, 0x0d, 0xb7, 0x89, 0xcb, 0xf5,
    0xda, 0xe4, 0xa6, 0x98, 0x22, 0x1c, 0x5e, 0x60, 0x9e, 0xa0, 0xe2, 0xdc,
    0x66, 0x58, 0x1a, 0x24, 0x0b, 0x35, 0x77, 0x49, 0xf3, 0xcd, 0x8f, 0xb1,
    0xd1, 0xef, 0xad, 0x93, 0x29, 0x17, 0x55, 0x6b, 0x44, 0x7a, 0x38, 0x06,
    0xbc, 0x82, 0xc0, 0xfe, 0x59, 0x67, 0x25, 0x1b, 0xa1, 0x9f, 0xdd, 0xe3,
    0xcc, 0xf2, 0xb0, 0x8e, 0x34, 0x0a, 0x48, 0x76, 0x16, 0x28, 0x6a, 0x54,
    0xee, 0xd0, 0x92, 0xac, 0x83, 0xbd, 0xff, 0xc1, 0x7b, 0x45, 0x07, 0x39,
    0xc7, 0xf9, 0xbb, 0x85, 0x3f, 0x01, 0x43, 0x7d, 0x52, 0x6c, 0x2e, 0x10,
    0xaa, 0x94, 0xd6, 0xe8, 0x88, 0xb6, 0xf4, 0xca, 0x70, 0x4e, 0x0c, 0x32,
    0x1d, 0x23, 0x61, 0x5f, 0xe5, 0xdb, 0x99, 0xa7, 0xb2, 0x8c, 0xce, 0xf0,
    0x4a, 0x74, 0x36, 0x08, 0x27, 0x19, 0x5b, 0x65, 0xdf, 0xe1, 0xa3, 0x9d,
    0xfd, 0xc3, 0x81, 0xbf, 0x05, 0x3b, 0x79, 0x47, 0x68, 0x56, 0x14, 0x2a,
    0x90, 0xae, 0xec, 0xd2, 0x2c, 0x12, 0x50, 0x6e, 0xd4, 0xea, 0xa8, 0x96,
    0xb9, 0x87, 0xc5, 0xfb, 0x41, 0x7f, 0x3d, 0x03, 0x63, 0x5d, 0x1f, 0x21,
    0x9b, 0xa5, 0xe7, 0xd9, 0xf6, 0xc8, 0x8a, 0xb4, 0x0e, 0x30, 0x72, 0x4c,
    0xeb, 0xd5, 0x97, 0xa9, 0x13, 0x2d, 0x6f, 0x51, 0x7e, 0x40, 0x02, 0x3c,
    0x86, 0xb8, 0xfa, 0xc4, 0xa4, 0x9a, 0xd8, 0xe6, 0x5c, 0x62, 0x20, 0x1e,
    0x31, 0x0f, 0x4d, 0x73, 0xc9, 0xf7, 0xb5, 0x8b, 0x75, 0x4b, 0x09, 0x37,
    0x8d, 0xb3, 0xf1, 0xcf, 0xe0, 0xde, 0x9c, 0xa2, 0x18, 0x26, 0x64, 0x5a,
    0x3a, 0x04, 0x46, 0x78, 0xc2, 0xfc, 0xbe, 0x80, 0xaf, 0x91, 0xd3, 0xed,
    0x57, 0x69, 0x2b, 0x15};

unsigned crc8(unsigned crc, unsigned char *data, size_t len)
{
    unsigned char *end;

    if (len == 0)
        return crc;
    crc ^= 0xff;
    end = data + len;
    do {
        crc = crc8_table[crc ^ *data++];
    } while (data < end);
    return crc ^ 0xff;
}
```

An 8-bit CRC will definitely give better error-detection performance than the 8-bit Fletcher checksum.  It may even be faster in this case!

Comment: Good point about CRC vs checksum :p What you are saying is that if I use 16 bit unsigned integers for sum1 and sum2 I can rewrite the while loop as `while(len--) sum2 += sum1 += *data++;` (I calculated that I can do up to 22 iteration before overflowing) ? If so what become the 2 last lines before the return statement ?

Comment: Your calculation of 22 is correct. Though depending on the processor you will probably be better off using a 32-bit integer type. In any case, once you get to the limit, you can either just use % 15 directly, or repeat (x & 0xf) + (x >> 4) until it is less than 16, then set to zero if it's 15. Whichever is faster for your processor.

Comment: Thanks for the code ! The processor is ... well, very very limited ... It is a 8 bit processor but its able to do add/sub and shifts on 16 bit data in just a few instructions. It can't manage 32 bit integers in an efficient way. My goal is to calculate the checksum as fast as possible on this 8MHz beast ! I will try to reduce your code now that my data's length is fixed at 17 bytes ...

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks a lot like the one given in the [Optimizations section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fletcher%27s_checksum#Optimizations) of the Wikipedia article on the Fletcher checksum. I guess [your source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925018/remake-of-fletcher-checksum-from-32bit-to-8) took it from there without proper attribution.

## Deferred reduction

Your code looks mostly right. However, you sum too much. If your input is only 17 bytes of data, then your maximal value of `sum2` will be `17*(17+1)/2*0xf + 0xf = 0x906`, which fits into an `uint16_t`. To reduce that to a single nibble, two reduction steps are sufficient. For `sum1`, the maximum will be `17*0xf + 0xf = 0x10e` which requires two reductions as well. So you could write

```
uint8_t fletcher(uint8_t *data) {
    uint16_t sum1 = 0xf, sum2 = 0xf, len = 17;
    while(len) {
        sum1 += *data++;
        sum2 += sum1;
        len--;
    };
    sum1 = (sum1 & 0x0f) + (sum1 >> 4);
    sum1 = (sum1 & 0x0f) + (sum1 >> 4);
    sum2 = (sum2 & 0x0f) + (sum2 >> 4);
    sum2 = (sum2 & 0x0f) + (sum2 >> 4);
    return sum2<<4 | sum1;
}
```

You could do further “optimizations” on the code, like

```
do { sum2 += ( sum1 += *data++ ); } while (--len);
```

or even manually unrolling that loop, but a good optimizing compiler should take care of this for you.

You can adapt the above considerations to other input lengths.

## Whole bytes as nibble stream

The above answer assumes that your data only contains unpacked nibbles, i.e. at most the least significant half of each byte is used. I might be wrong here, but I guess that if you were dealing with whole bytes, the solution most in the spirit of Fletcher's checksum would be to treat them as a sequence of twice as many nibbles, e.g.

```
        sum1 += *data & 0xf;
        sum2 += sum1;
        sum1 += *data >> 4;
        sum2 += sum1;
        ++data;
        --len;
```

There might be more efficient ways to write this as fewer optimizations. Your compiler may or may not be able to find one of them.

## Quality of the checksum

> but may be wrong in the fletcher way and not provide the expected error detection ...

I'm not sure how useful a fletcher checksum here really is. Perhaps some *real* [CRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) with 8 bit output would better suite your needs in terms of error checking.

Comment: Oopsey.  The input data is bytes.  The poster said nothing about the data being restricted to 0..0xf.  Then your `16*(16+1)/2*0xf + 0xf = 0x807` should be `16*(16+1)/2*0xff + 0xf = 0x8787`.  Which then requires three iterations to do a modulo 15.  Similarly `16*0xf + 0xf = 0xff` should be `16*0xff + 0xf = 0xfff`.  That also requires three iterations.  Also the original question said that there was 17 bytes of data, not 16.  So the above amounts should be a tad more, but three iterations for the modulo's are still sufficient.

Comment: Dang.  You were headed the right way, but then you went into a ditch.  The solution "most in the spirit of Fletcher's checksum" would take more than twice as long as the correct solution.  Just sum the bytes with a `do { sum2 += sum1 += *data++} while (--part);', where `part` is less than the number that would overflow `sum2` if all of the data bytes were `0xff`.  Do the modulo and repeat the loop until `len` bytes are processed.

Comment: By the way, based on the comment from the original poster to my question where they calculated 22, the data bytes are in fact bytes, not nybbles.

Comment: And I just noticed an error in the original code I hadn't noticed before.  `(x >> 4) + (x & 0xf)` does not complete the `x % 15` operation when `x` is 15.  There needs to be a final `if (x == 15) x = 0;`.

Comment: @MarkAdler, are you sure that simply summing whole bytes has the same error detection features that summing nibbles would have? Performance is nice, but I'd hesitate to call that “correct” unless actually verified in some way. By the way, the `0xf` is simply `-0` in ones' complement notation. As long as you use the same convention on both ends, reducing to `+0` is not strictly neccessary.

Comment: Yes, the modulo 15 is strictly necessary to assure that you can't get two different answers when comparing checksums that actually would be equal if computed correctly.

Comment: Not only does summing whole bytes provide the same error detection performance, it is actually mathematically identical.  If the nybbles are `x` and `y`, then `(x + 16y) modulo 15 === (x + 15y + y) modulo 15 === (x + y) modulo 15`.

Comment: Wow, so much comments ... and so much things I still don't understand ... I'll have to figure out what a nibble is first I gess ... @MvG I am not dead set on the fletcher algorithm, I just need a fast to compute (8/16 bit uC @ 8MHz) error detection method with a 8 bit result, it will be transmitted over a serial link that already have a parity check for each byte but I need a way to tell if the whole message (1 byte address, 16 byte data) is not corrupted.

Comment: @MarkAdler, you are of course correct about the byte processing having the same effect here. ust have been pretty late when I wrote my comment. About the necessity of the mod 15, I still disagree: as long as both ends do the same computation, any representation of 0 will do to verify the checksum.

Comment: @yent, a nibble is half a byte, i.e. 4 bits. I suggest you implement Fletcher, implement some CRC, and then compare whether performance forces you to use Fletcher. If not, then I guess CRC will yield better error detection.

Comment: Ok, I'll give CRC-8 a try, but from the look of the algorithm I think it will be heavier on the cpu since I see 3 loops with a bunch of ANDing and XORing inside ...

Comment: @MvG Just did some analysis of the CRC-8 algorithm on 16 byte data, I find the cpu cycle count to be around 1500, the fletcher algorithm need about 130 cpu cycles ... I could reduce the cycle count for the CRC-8 using a static lookup table but it will still be at least twice as expensive as the fletcher algorithm, I wonder if it is really worth the effort ...

Comment: You are incorrect about "any representation of 0 will do".  That is only true if both sides do _exactly_ the same computation to get the same representation of 0.  If the placement of the modulo operations occur at different points in the stream (e.g. depending on where chunks are cut being fed to the algorithm based on buffer sizes), then you can get a different representation of 0 for the same input data.  Then the two checksums on each end would not match!  What the heck is the problem with doing the calculation correctly?  Modulo 15 is modulo 15 and not sometimes modulo 15.

Comment: A "nybble" (note the "y") is a term for a word of four bits.  As compared to a "byte", which is a word of eight bits.  Each byte has two nybbles.  Cute, eh?

Comment: @MarkAdler: The Wikipedia article is titled [Nibble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble), giving “nybble” as an alternative spelling. The corresponding [talk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Nibble#Move_to_.22nybble.22.3F) is somewhat controversial. I take it both are accepted, and preferences might vary between communities.

Comment: Well, Wikipedia and the alleged current common usage of "nibble" is incorrect.  I was programming 8-bit machines in the late 70's and early 80's, and the original term and the spelling in the magazines (Byte, Dr. Dobbs, etc.) was _always_ "nybble".